# Htaccess RegEx redirect first subdirectoriy to a single file

Tags: regex, .htaccess, redirect

I need to redirect the first Subdirectory of a URL to a file, remove tailoring subdirectories, add tailoring slash, and remove www.

```
example.com/sub1/sub2/sub3/ -> example.com/sub1/sub2/ (no need of sub3,sub4,...)

example.com/sub1/sub2/ -> example.com/client.php?url=sub1?token=sub2

example.com/sub1/ -> example.com/client.php?url=sub1

example.com/client.php?url=sub1&token=sub2 -> example.com/sub1/sub2/
```

Additionally:

```
www.example.com/* -> example.com/*

example.com/sub1 -> example.com/sub1/

example.com/something.php (or .html, ...) should not be touched
```

I did a lot of trial and error the last days and tried a lot of approaches I found here in the forums, but couldn't get it to work properly. Finally I learned that RegEx is mighty but I really hate it!

Edit1 - code added
Edit2 - old code removed, new code added - after some more hours I'm nearly there

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
#remove www.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.com [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.comt/$1 [L,R=301]

#rewrite dynamic url to static, needs THE_REQUEST not to get into a loop
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|POST|HEAD)\ /client\.php\?url=([^&\ ]+)&token=([^&\ ]+)
RewriteRule ^ %2/%3/? [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|POST|HEAD)\ /client\.php\?url=([^&\ ]+)
RewriteRule ^ %2/? [L,R=301]

#adds tailing slash to nice url and redirects
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])$ /$1/ [L,R=301]

# strip everything after the 2. subdirectory and redirect to change url
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/(.+)$ $1/$2/ [L,R=301]

#redirect nice url to dynamic url
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$ client.php?url=$1&token=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$ client.php?url=$1 [L]
```

The one thing I am missing is, that I want to call the correct dynamic url based on the static url and additionally get rid of the last subdirectory.

```
example.com/userID/tokenID ->
example.com/client.php?url=userID&token=tokenID ->
-> displayed URL in browser should change to example.com/userID/

I would prefer not to show the tokenID in the displayed URL.
```

Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: "I did a lot of trial and error the last days and tried a lot of approaches". Show a few of those approaches

Comment: sure, I added the last one I tried